# How to write a list containing tuples to a file in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, 3d, tuples

I'm busy constructing a Physics simulator as a school project and need to store a list of shapes in a file to be read in when the program is loaded again. How do I store the list and return it to its original state, especially considering some of the list items are tuples or lists themselves.

This doesn't work:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:

        f.write("\n".join(objs))
```

I expected to be able to write to a file but errors keep springing up as I can't write tuples.

Comment: What's the error message? And please post the complete code (`objs` is not shown).

Comment: Hi Grud. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you include what you have tried and what error is raised? This will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write `objs` to file as a string?

```
objs = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

with open('filename', 'w') as f:

        f.write(str(objs))
```